# Custom Transformer to Filter out Outliers

Tags: python, scikit-learn, transformer-model

I'm trying to build a transformer that will allow me to specify a feature and then filter out any outliers along this feature. An outlier is an observation that has a value for that feature which deviates from the median by more than 2 times the width of the distribution.

Below is the code I currently have. There are 3 lines of code I'm not sure if they are correct. Please let me know if I did it wrong and how to correct them. Thanks!

```
import numpy as np

class FilterOutliersTransformer(base.BaseEstimator, base.TransformerMixin):
    
    def __init__(self, feature):
        
        self.feature = feature
        
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        
        Q1 = np.percentile(X.loc[:, self.feature], 25)
        Q3 = np.percentile(X.loc[:, self.feature], 75)
        
        deviation_allowed = 1.5*(Q3 - Q1)
        lower_bound = Q1 - deviation_allowed
        upper_bound = Q3 + deviation_allowed
        
        # not sure here 1
        self.params_ = [lower_bound, upper_bound]

        # not sure here 2   
        return self    
    
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        
        X_transformed = X[(X[self.feature] > self.params_[0]) & (X[self.feature] < self.params_[1])]
        
        # not sure here 3 
        return X_transformed
```

Comment: You should almost certainly be calling the constructor(s) of the parent class, for example by adding a line `super().__init__()` to your constructor.  Also 2 of the three lines you marked as "not sure" are simple return statements; they cannot be "incorrect" in the sense of being a bug.  It depends on how you want to use the functions in the rest of your program.  And `return self` is very rarely useful, since the calling code must already have a reference to `self` in order to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Sklearn does not allow `Transformers` to change the number of data-points that comes out. The reason is that we have an option to apply similar filtering to target value(y).

This issues comes up when you plan to place this Transformer in a pipeline, when you have a classifier/regressor at the end of pipeline.

```py
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import base
import numpy as np

X ,y = datasets.make_classification()

class FilterOutliersTransformer(base.BaseEstimator, base.TransformerMixin):
    
    def __init__(self,):
        
        pass
        
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        
        return X[:2]


pipe = pipeline.make_pipeline(FilterOutliersTransformer(), 
           linear_model.LogisticRegression()).fit(pd.DataFrame(X),y)
```

You might get an

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [98, 100]

Use Imblearn for processes like this. See [here](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_outlier_rejections.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-applications-plot-outlier-rejections-py) for a similar example.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for.

```py
import numpy as np

class FilterOutliersTransformer(base.BaseEstimator, base.TransformerMixin):
    
    def __init__(self, feature):
        
        self.feature = feature
        
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        
        Q1 = np.percentile(X.loc[:, self.feature], 25)
        Q3 = np.percentile(X.loc[:, self.feature], 75)
        
        deviation_allowed = 1.5*(Q3 - Q1)
        lower_bound = Q1 - deviation_allowed
        upper_bound = Q3 + deviation_allowed
        
        self.params_ = [lower_bound, upper_bound]
            
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        
        X_transformed = X[(X[self.feature] > self.params_[0]) & (X[self.feature] < self.params_[1])]
        
        return X[X_transformed[self.feature[0]].notnull()]
```